Profile checkboxes not showing when included with contribution page, but appear when used on Wordpress page w/ shortcode
I've run into an issue with profiles that previously worked... Currently, when I edit a profile and preview a field that is supposed to be rendered as a checkbox, the checkbox does not appear. When that same profile is used on a contribution page, I also do not see the fields that are supposed to render with a checkbox.
However, if I show that same profile on a simple wordpress page using a shortcode, the fields with checkboxes render correctly.
Here is a current example:
https://crm.4dministries.org/test/
(this is a simple wordpress page with a shortcut to render the profile)
https://crm.4dministries.org/4dcrm/contribute/transact/?reset=1&id=43
(this is a sample contribution page that is set-up to use the same profile as above, but the checkboxes don't appear)
The resulting HTML in each of the pages is different, but I am not sure how to troubleshoot at this point.. I did try creating new profiles without luck. I did notice that I was able to get a checkbox to appear if I selected the field Contribution-Send Receipt, but I don't think that is an actual field in the database, only a checkbox that results in the action of sending receipt.
Wordpress 6.6.1
PHP version 8.1.29
CiviCRM 5.76.2
Extensions
Action Provider: Version 1.150
AdminUI (Preview): Version 5.76.2
Advanced Import: Version 1.6
AuthX: Version 5.76.2
Civi-Import: Version 5.76.2
CiviCampaign: Version 5.76.2
CiviContribute: Version 5.76.2
CiviCRM Export to Excel: Version 2.6.0
CiviCRM Log Viewer: Version 2.1.1
CiviCRM Report Error: Version 4.0
CiviEvent: Version 5.76.2
CiviGrant: Version 5.76.2
CiviMail: Version 5.76.2
CiviMobileAPI: Version 6.5.1
CiviReport: Version 5.76.2
CiviRules: Version 3.11
Civisualize. The missing data visualization extension: Version 6.3
CiviTutorial: Version 1.6
CKEditor4: Version 5.76.2
Contact Editor: Version 2.6
Contact Layout Editor: Version 2.3.1
CSS/JS minifier for AssetBuilder: Version 1.3
CSV GUI Import to api: Version 1.13
CSV Import Helper: Version 1.2.0
Custom search framework: Version 5.76.2
Data Processor: Version 1.112
Easy Copy: Version 1.3
Edit Line Item Extension: Version 2.7
ExtendedReport: Version 6.0.2
Firewall: Version 1.5.10
FlexMailer: Version 5.76.2
FormBuilder: Version 5.76.2
Form Core: Version 5.76.2
Form Processor: Version 2.0.9
Geocoder: Version 1.13
group2summary: Version 1.7
Joinery's More Summary Fields: Version 1.2
Mosaico: Version 3.5.1709296836
Move Contribution: Version 2.12
Payment Shared: Version 1.3
PDF API: Version 2.20
Radio Buttons: Version 1.5
reCAPTCHA: Version 5.76.2
Recurring Buttons: Version 1.2
Referral Source: Version 1.1
Report Plus: Version 2.8.1
SearchKit: Version 5.76.2
Sequential credit notes: Version 5.76.2
SparkPost integration: Version 1.7
Stripe Payment Processor: Version 6.11.2
Summary Fields: Version 5.0.3
Sweet Alert: Version 1.6
TextSelect: Version 2.1.0
The Island Theme: Version 2.4.1
Theme: Greenwich: Version 5.76.2
twilio: Version 1.2.2
US County Loader: Version 2.1

